# Failed to connect to remote machine. Verify the SSH service connection details. All configured authentication methods failed

Tags: ssh, azure-pipelines

My SSH configuration for Azure pipeline worked fine until I upgraded ubuntu from Ubuntu20 to Ubuntu 22. Now I get this message:
`##[error]Failed to connect to the remote machine. Verify the SSH service connection details. Error: Error: All configured authentication methods failed.`

How can I debug this? I can ssh to my server using my ssh key without any issues.

Is there a way for me to know more about the issue and debug it?

Also, there is this announcement on Azure pipeline that says:

> Azure DevOps proceeds in rollout of changes to permanently disable communication over TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1 and weak cipher suites of TLS 1.2. If your tools are dependent on legacy TLS for communication with Azure DevOps, please take necessary actions to enable TLS 1.2, as detailed in the blog.

Could this be related?
All help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue and announcement. Were you able to fix it? Was the announcement related? thanks

Comment: Same issue here, my issue is with machines that change IP but still having the same DNS. Debugging with scp because ssh is interactive and cannot debug, I realize that the issue is with the HostKey Checking, with -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no it works like a charm. Big problem then: SSH task or SSH Service Connector cannot define it.
Azure Pipelines has reported this since 2019 but not fixed yet

Answer (score 15):

This solution work for me.

```
key type ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms
```

which lead to a solution by adding,

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa
```

in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and restarting sshd.

Seems newer Ubuntu 22.04 has changed default accepted key types and this plugin no longer worked despite SSH command working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue, using an Azure service connection in a Azure Pipeline.

My task:

- SSH task in a azure linux virtual machine
  Error:
- *failed-to-connect-to-remote-machine-verify-the-ssh-service-connection-details*

My success solution:

- Create a ssh key ( in my case directly in Azure Portal, where the key will be saved for other jobs.)
- After create the key, i have downloaded the private Key from Azure portal.
- Next, i have added this private key in  my service connection
- Finally, i have added this public key ssh in the authorized_keys file, in the Linux Virtual Machine.

After this, the pipeline working fine.